# How to pull a ms access report data to a query?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-reports

I am trying to pull data from a MS Access report (repInvoices and form frmInvoice) and keep it in MS Access query(qryQuote). I know how it can be done from form but not from a report. I did research in stack exchange and google but I didn't find anything that is helpful. Can any of you help me out? Following is the query that I had been trying to work on. I kept form on following example:

```sql
SELECT MAX([oi].[Quote]) 
FROM  ORDER_Shipment AS os 
INNER JOIN ORDER_Items AS oi 
ON os.Id = oi.Id 
AND oi.MaterialId =  [Reports]![repInvoices]![MaterialId]                       
WHERE os.InvoiceNumber= CAST('& Me.InvoiceID' AS VARCHAR)
```

Two last lines in above query is the place where I need to get data from the report.Also, I know both of above are not correct right now.
`[Reports]![repInvoices]![MaterialId]` It gives me an error `JOIN expression not supported`.
 Also, I have to use report InvoiceID here `CAST('& Me.InvoiceID' AS VARCHAR)`

Comment: "SELECT ...blablabla... AND oi.MaterialID = '" & reports!repInvoices!MaterialID & "' " & ...blablabla

Comment: Why isn't the AND criteria within the WHERE clause? Why are you using Cast()? How can query use Me qualifier?